# I accidentally made my model transparent. How do I fix this?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, 3d-view

I'm new to blender and when I was modeling a shotgun, it turned transparent and command Z did nothing. I don't know what button I pressed or what I accidentally clicked but I'm not sure what to do. What should I do to fix this? [image: Transparent shotgun sideview]

Comment: to add to the answers, press shortcut Alt Z to switch to opaque mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you toggled the "X-Ray" visibility.
You can toggle it using this icon in the header bar of the 3D viewport.

[image: X-ray visibility]

More info :
your model is not technically transparent. It is only a functionality of the 3D viewport to help modelers see through they're meshes without having only the wireframe.

Answer (score 1):

You've enabled *X-Ray* mode. Just click on the button (see image) in the *Viewport Shading* menu to disable it.

[image: xray]